# Shell: Sortear arquivo cujo nome contenha espaço em branco

Tags: shell-script

Utilizando shell script, estou criando um arquivo `script.sh` que automatiza algumas tarefas para mim. Nele eu preciso sortear um arquivo do diretório atual para realizar algumas tarefas. Estou sorteando o arquivo com o comando abaixo:

```
shuf -n1 -e $(ls)
```

O código funciona perfeitamente quando o nome do arquivo não contém espaço em branco (ex: `relatorio.pdf`). Porém, para arquivos com espaço em branco (ex: `relatorio mensal.pdf`), o sorteio acaba quebrando o nome do arquivo (no meu exemplo, fica `relatorio` e `mensal.pdf`).

Gostaria que o comando `shuf` sorteasse e retornasse sempre o nome completo do arquivo, mesmo que este contenha espaço em branco. Alguém sabe como fazer isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O parâmetro `-e` foi utilizado incorretamente. Ele indica que cada argumento passado será tratado como uma entrada. Desta forma, `relatorio` é um argumento e `mensal.pdf` é outro.

O comando que resolve o problema é

```
ls | shuf -n 1
```

Desta forma, executa-se a primeira instrução: `ls` (lista o conteúdo do diretório). O resultado é passado à instrução `shuf`, que sorteará uma linha aleatória dentre as retornadas pelo comando `ls`. Isto é dito com o parâmetro `-n 1`.